# How can I query for entries of a given type which point to a particular other entry by URI on a particular field?

Tags: elementquery, graphql, headless

I can run this query:

```
mySectionEntries(myEntryRelationField: "target-id") {
  ...
}
```

This gets entries from section `mySection` which point to an entry with ID `target-id` on the entries relation field `myEntryRelationField`.

**I want to do the same thing, but filter for entries which relate to the other entry by URI rather than by ID.**

The autogenerated docs for `myEntryRelationField` just say its type is `[QueryArgument]` (though it doesn't seem to demand an array as the type would suggest; it seems to accept a single string). The docs for `QueryArgument` say "represents a value to be using in Craft element queries. It can be an integer, a string, or a boolean value."

If I understand right, I should be able to do things you can do for regular non-GQL element queries, so I'm looking at https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html. I can't find what I'm looking for, however.

The docs at https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/graphql.html don't shine any more light, as far as I can tell.

I found that I can use `relatedToEntries` instead of `myEntryRelationField` like this:

```
mySectionEntries(relatedToEntries: {uri: "target-uri"}) {
  ...
}
```

However, this doesn't guarantee that they're related via the field `myEntryRelationField`, and I'd like to enforce that.